# unexpected output for map inside of do

Tags: clojure

Why doesn't this produce the output I expect?

```
(defn test-fn []
  (do
    (println "start")
    (map #(println (+ % 1)) '(1 2 3))
    (println "done")))
```

It outputs

```
start
done
```

Whereas I would expect

```
start
2 3 4
done
```

Comment: Hopefully you got a good answer in the IRC channel :) Good luck with learning Clojure!

Comment: Yes! Thanks for answering my question on #clojure, Isaac..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`map` is lazy, and `do` does not force it. If you want to force the evaluation of a lazy sequence, use `doall` or `dorun`.

```
(defn test-fn []
  (do
    (println "start")
    (dorun (map #(println (+ % 1)) '(1 2 3)))
    (println "done")))
```